# Close the open browser by Javascript in PhoneGap App

Tags: cordova

Currently we are working with PhoneGap app. In app we have open 3rd party link for information.

Like
[Click](http://www.example.com/)

Now by JavaScript looking to close this link and back to app.

Answer (score 1):

If you are opening an external browser, there is no way that you can inject javascript code into it.

You should check [inAppBrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser), so you can open the link inside your application, and you can close it via javascript when you want, and make your logic.

Happy coding!